# Adjustment Required for Force between Plates of a Parallel Plate Capacitor

Tags: capacitance

The parallel plate Capacitor is not an Infinite sized charged sheet system. But in Most derivations of Force between the Charged plates due to the electric field and charges between/on the plates is shown to be that of Infinite sized sheet. Is there a correction factor be be applied to the expression of Force between the plates of a Capacitor to make sure that the electric field E is due to Finite sized sheet and not Infinite sized charged sheet system ?

Answer (score 1):

For parallel circular disks, an approximate correction factor derived by Kirchoff in 1877 is

$$1+\frac{b}{\pi}\ln\left(\frac{16\pi}{b}-1\right)$$

where $b$ is the ratio of the disk separation to the disk radius. For some other approximations, see [this article](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/b6e2/f46943e54b6f4e8a0d6fc2cbd5d1d31aa5ff.pdf).